# Using a connection string in a app.config file in a .cs file

Tags: c#, database-connection, app-config

I've got a connection string to my database in a my app.config file. I want to using the app.config file rather than copying and pasting the string in the section i want to use it is.

My app.config file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Code_Churn_Analyiser.Properties.Settings.SVN_ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\SVN .mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and my .cs file is currently like this:

```
    private void sendToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +"password=password;server=serverurl;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +                                                       "database=database; " + "connection timeout=30");
}
```

I know that this is wrong but want to use the config file instead.

Can anyone help me in how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Code_Churn_Analyiser.Properties.Settings.SVN_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Note : try to keep the name of the connectionstring simpler for readability purposes.
Also,Your assembly also needs a reference to **System.Configuration.dll**

Comment: I don't seem to be able to give the reference System.Configuration.dll

Comment: Why is it so? go to the references & check.

Comment: Under your Project, Right click on References -->Add Reference | Under assemblies --> Framework ,search system.Configuration -->click on OK. the reference will be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the [`ConnectionStrings` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx) of your application-configuration file, you have to ...

- [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the `System.Configuration`-dll.
- add this to the top of the file:

  ```
  using System.Configuration;
  ```

Then you can access it in this way:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Code_Churn_Analyiser.Properties.Settings.SVN_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to give the reference System.Configuration.dll

Comment: @FraserMunro: my answer contains a link to the msdn page which explains what to do. Have you read it? You just need to right-click on the _refernces_ item under your project. You find the `System.Configuration`-dll under the `.NET`-tab.